# How to download file from server (sso and https)

Tags: https, single-sign-on

It is possible to download a file from a server that use HTTPS + SSO (Single Sign ON) by means command line (of course using linux)?

The Single Sign On system run with shibbolet process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED!!

```
wget  --save-cookies sso.cookie --keep-session-cookies --header="Referer: https://serverCheckPoint/" 'https://serverCheckPoint/Shibboleth.sso/Login?target=https://ServerCheckPoint/path_Of_The_File_To_Read'

curl -b sso.cookie -c 2sso.cookie -L -k -f -s -S https://IDP_SERVER/PATH_of_loginPAge --data "USER=yourUser&password=YOURPASSWORD" -o localfile.html

wget -v --load-cookies 2sso.cookie --save-cookies auth2.cookie --keep-session-cookies https://CheckPointServer/Path_of_data/DATA_to_DOWNLOAD
```

the file sso.cookie, 2sso.cookie, auth.cookie are used in order to store the session and the SAML token.
In case there are problem with certificates you should to disable the check for the TLS certificates